# Tutorials for drop down menu search in PHP

Tags: php

I'm really new to PHP still and I have learnt a little from the community but I still have a lot to learn and I was hoping you guys could give me advice on this question.

My question is about drop down menus. I currently have a drop down menu that pulls information from a table. The information displays ingredients which I can select from the drop down menu. Now I want to be able to use these ingredients to search for recipes in my recipe table but I don't know how I would go about it.

My `ingredients` table contains two fields.

`ingredient id` and  `recipe id`

My `recipe` table contains two fields

`recipe id` and `recipe name`

My `recipeingredients` table which is a composite key has two fields

`recipe id` and `ingredient id`

My HTML code below is the drop down menu

```
<form id="searchForm">
<form action="<?php echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="GET">
<h3> Search your recipe here </h3>
<fieldset>
    Ingredient 1:<select name= "dropdown1" id = "drop1"/>
    <?php
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    ?> 
    <option value="<?php echo $line['ingredientname'];?>"> <?php echo $line['ingredientname'];?> </option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    Ingredient 2:<select name = "dropdown2" id = "drop2"/>
    <?php
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    ?> 
    <option value="<?php echo $line['ingredientname'];?>"> <?php echo $line['ingredientname'];?> </option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

I have a feeling that I may need a join but like I said, I'm new to this so please be gentle.

Comment: You should be using `PDO` or `mysqli`, not the `mysql_*` extensions - they are deprecated and will be removed in PHP 5.5

Comment: Yes, you need a `SELECT` from your recipies table that has a `WHERE` clause using an `IN` operator. That should get you started!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it. Schema first:

```
CREATE TABLE ingredients (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE recipe (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE recipe_ingredients (
  recipe_id INTEGER,
  ingredient_id INTEGER
);
```

Now for a query. All recipes that contain a numbered ingredient:

```
SELECT
  recipe.name
FROM
  recipe
  INNER JOIN recipe_ingredients ri ON (recipe.id = ri.recipe_id)
WHERE
  ri.ingredient_id = 1;
```

All recipes that contain at least one of several ingredients:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  recipe.name
FROM
  recipe
  INNER JOIN recipe_ingredients ri ON (recipe.id = ri.recipe_id)
WHERE
  ri.ingredient_id IN (1, 2, 5);
```

Or, if you want to search by ingredient name:

```
SELECT
  recipe.name
FROM
  recipe
  INNER JOIN recipe_ingredients ri ON (recipe.id = ri.recipe_id)
  INNER JOIN ingredients i ON (ri.ingredient_id = i.id)
WHERE
  i.name = 'egg';
```

The first of these queries is a bit quicker, since there are less joins, and it is faster to search for an integer key than a string. That said, with the volumes of data you are likely dealing with here, it probably won't make much difference. The thing to remember with joins is that, so long as your table design is simple, just join "matching" items (e.g. a primary key with a foreign key) and then trim your `SELECT` columns to what you need.

I've made [a live forkable demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ff64/3).

Comment: i.name = 'egg'; won't that just pull out recipes with egg in though? I want to be able to grab recipes from the ingredients from the drop down menu. I'm sorry, I'm new to this and that's probably a stupid question.

Comment: Hmm... are you looking to search for "any recipes containing all of these ingredients", where either one or several ingredients have been presented? The above will work for one ingredient, a small change will get it to work for "containing any of these ingredients", and "containing all" needs more joins.

Comment: You are correct, I want to be able to search for a recipe by searching with multiple ingredients.

Comment: Multiple as in a known number of ingredients, or an arbitrary number? You have two in your code, but could you want to search on one or three ingredients? Do you mean "contains all these ingredients" or "contains any of these ingredients"?

Comment: Well I plan to add a few drop down menus but hypothetically speaking lets see I have 3 drop down menus. eggs, chicken and bread. With them three ingredients it should search for recipes that have them ingredients in. The recipe doesn't need to contain all them ingredients.

Comment: Ah, "any ingredients" is an easy change (see update). I suggest you modify your menus so that their values are the primary key of each ingredient, so they are easy to filter. You can just do `(int) $_GET['dropdown1']` to get the untainted value to inject into your query (they then need to have comma separators to be injected into the `IN`).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29364/discussion-between-lawrence-smith-and-halfer)

Comment: I rarely have time for chat requests, and they can often be rather open-ended. There is _plenty_ for you now to work with - give it a try and report back?

Comment: I got it working in the end.

SELECT `id`,`name`, `step1`, `step2`, `step3`, `image`, `reference`
        FROM `recipe` r
        INNER JOIN `recipe_ingredients` ri
        ON r.id = ri.recipe_id
        WHERE ri.ingredient_id IN (".$ingredient1.",".$ingredient2.",".$ingredient3.")

This is how I accomplished it.

Comment: @Lawrence, I am pleased that my assistance did not go to waste. I trust that after my efforts, I may look forward to your accepting this answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I had marked this as answered. My apologies!