# Grabbing information from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I am able to pull the recipe name from the recipe table but I want to be able to grab the ingredients required from the ingredients table. I know it's to do with JOINS but I'm new to JOINS.

This is the ingredients table
[image: This is the ingredients table]

This is the recipeingredients table, this has two primary keys so I am able to assign multiple ingredients to one recipe
[image: This is the recipeingredients table, this has two primary keys so I am able to assign multiple ingredients to one recipe]

This is the recipe table
[image: This is the recipe table]

This is the search script

```
<?php
    $query = $_GET['query'];
    // gets value sent over search form

    $min_length = 3;


    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query);


        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recipes
            WHERE (`recipename` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`ingredients` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());





        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
            // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

                echo "<p>Recipe:".$results['recipename']."</p><p>Ingredients:".$results['ingredients']."<p>Instructions:".$results['instructions']."</p>";
                // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
            }

        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "No results";
        }

    }
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
?>
```

ingredients sample data

[image]

recipeingredients sample data

[image]

Recipe Table sample data

[image]

Comment: what is your desired output and post some sample data..

Comment: If you are new to JOINS the most sensible thing to do would be to learn about it, instead of asking.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @raheelshan I want to be able to search for a recipe and it display the recipe and the ingredients

Comment: @PHPfan I have been reading up on them for the past few days but I'm a really slow learner which is why I was hoping for a bit of help.

Comment: Oops! You asked [an essentially identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16344498/472495) yesterday, for which I provided some pointers. Instead of responding to my helpful hints, you've asked the question again, by which time I'd created a full answer. This is a form of [crossposting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_posting), which as you can see, risks creating duplicate effort. Please don't do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    r.*,
    i.*
FROM recipe AS r
INNER JOIN recipeingredients AS ri
    ON ri.recipeid = r.recipeid
INNER JOIN  ingredients AS i
    ON i.ingredientid = ri.ingredientid
WHERE r.recipename = 'Beans On Toast'
```

This will give you recipe and its ingrediants.

EDITS

Here is how you can do it.

```
$query  ="  SELECT
                r.*,
                i.*
            FROM recipe AS r
            INNER JOIN recipeingredients AS ri
                ON ri.recipeid = r.recipeid
            INNER JOIN  ingredients AS i
                ON i.ingredientid = ri.ingredientid
            WHERE r.recipename = 'Beans On Toast'";

$raw_results = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: How do I incorporate this into my PHP though, so I can type any recipe in a form and it display the recipe and ingredients. That was my initial question.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it didn't work but that's probably something stupid that I'm doing.