# echo $_GET['id'] not displaying anything

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page in which a user chooses a recipe which has a unique ID, they are then sent to another page where the information for that recipe is displayed but it is not displaying anything.

```
$recipes = mysql_query("
        SELECT DISTINCT `name`, `step1`, `step2`, `step3`, `image`, `reference`
        FROM `recipe` r
        INNER JOIN `recipe_ingredients` ri
        ON r.id = ri.recipe_id
        WHERE ri.ingredient_id IN (".$ingredient1.",".$ingredient2.",".$ingredient3.")
    ");
```

This is the query on the main page, this allows the user to choose a set of ingredients and then retrieve recipes from them.

```
echo '<form action="recipe.php?id=<?php echo $recipe_id;?>" method="POST">';
        echo '<input id="search" name="Look" type="Submit" value="Look" >';
        echo '</form>';
```

Under each recipe there is a button a user presses, this will send the user to the specific recipe.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `image`
FROM `recipe` 
WHERE `id` = ".$_GET['id']." LIMIT 1");
```

This is the query I'm running on the results page (recipe.php)

Further down the page I ran this.

```
<?php
echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

It didn't display an ID and in the url I was displayed with this:

> "recipe.php?id="

There is data in the table so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `<form>` is using POST; you'll need to access the variable as `$_POST['id']`, or change the form's method to GET

Comment: i don't see you setting `$recipe_id` anywhere

Comment: @SamuelCook should it be something else?

Comment: you should parameterize your variables in that sql statement.

Comment: @Lawrence: I seem to remember [I was helping you, with extended notes in chat](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16344498/472495) and you didn't reply. Please take care to respond to everyone who helps you, especially if you are not providing answers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following echo syntax is incorrect:

```
echo '<form action="recipe.php?id=<?php echo $recipe_id;?>" method="POST">';
```

should be:

```
echo '<form action="recipe.php?id='.$recipe_id.'" method="POST">';
```

I don't see where you are setting `$recipe_id`, which appears to be the root of your problem.

It is unclear where you are trying to retrieve the elusive `$recipe_id` from.

If your trying to pull it in from `$recipes` then you should include it in your sql statement:

```
SELECT `id`,....
```

then pull it in after your `$recipes->fetch_assoc()`:

```
$recipe_id = $recipes['id'];
```

Comment: I've probably done this wrong but do you mean like this?

 while ($recipe = mysql_fetch_assoc($recipes)) {
  $recipe_id = $recipes['id'];

Comment: `$recipe_id = $recipe['id'];` << `$recipe` not `$recipes`. but yes something along those lines.

Comment: it works now but I had to use POST in the form method and GET in the query on the recipe.php.

Thanks anyway XD

Answer (score 1):

First of all before making any queries to the database make sure that all $variables that you use in the query are escaped, because you can get hacked very easily. Escape like this:

```
$_GET['variable'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['variable']);
```

Integers can be escaped like this

```
$_GET['variable'] = (int) $_GET['variable'];
```

You are doing it wrong, you can add recipe_id as hidden input field and later read it after the form submittion.
Here is example form.

```
<form action="/recipe.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="recipe_id" value="<?= $recipe_id ?>" />
    <input id="search" name="Look" type="Submit" value="Look" />
</form>
```

And after the form is submitted you can do something like this:

```
$recipe_id = (int) $_POST['recipe_id'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `image` FROM `recipe` WHERE `id` = $recipe_id LIMIT 1");
```

But I think you main problem is that $recipe_id in the form is just an empty variable, check that first :).

Answer (score -1):

```
// change this
echo '<form action="recipe.php?id=<?php echo $recipe_id;?>" method="POST">';
// to this
echo '<form action="recipe.php?id=' . $recipe_id .'" method="POST">';
```

Change the line where you echo the form to something like this... You were trying to echo twice before (echo within the echo)... This works though.

Comment: is he not talking about the `recipe.php?id=<?php echo $recipe_id;?>` part?

Comment: @DannyHearnah the question wasn't 100% clear, but I guess so... Updated my answer to reflect that.